# getFollowersList in twitter4j doesn't retrieve followers

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Here is my code:

```
int favouritesCount = user.getFavouritesCount();
int followersCount = user.getFollowersCount();
int friendsCount = user.getFriendsCount();
long userId = user.getId();
System.out.println("FavouritesCount: " + favouritesCount + ", followersCount: " + followersCount + ", friendsCount: " + friendsCount);
ArrayList<User> followers = new ArrayList<User>();
long nextCursor = 0;
do {
    PagableResponseList<User> usersResponse = twitter.getFollowersList(user.getScreenName(), nextCursor);
    System.out.println("size() of first iteration:" + usersResponse.size());
    nextCursor = usersResponse.getNextCursor();
    followers.addAll(usersResponse);
} while ( nextCursor > 0);

System.out.println( followers.size() > 0 ? "Getting followers:" : "No followers.");

for ( User user : followers) {
    System.out.println(user.getScreenName() + ", id: " + user.getId());
}
```

And this is output I get:

```
FavouritesCount: 0, followersCount: 1, friendsCount: 1
size() of first iteration:0
No followers.
```

What am I doing wrong here? User is authenticated through OAuth, everything is fine except this part of code simply does not work. Correct are the numbers of follower's and friend's count, but I have problem to see followers.

Please, help!

Best,
D

Comment: `followers.size` was intially 0 , you add `usersResponse` to it whose `size()` is 0 hence `followers.size()` is 0. What is the confusion ?

Comment: usersResponse.size() should be 1, since followersCount = 1 and I've checked on the website. Thanks for comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved the problem. Actually, the error lies in following line:

```
long nextCursor = 0;
```

It should be set

```
long nextCursor = -1;
```

as documentation very clearly "says": [link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/misc/cursoring).

Thanks again!